# Using MongoDB with Docker compose, cannot authenticate & download data from local database

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use MongoDB with Docker compose in Windows powershell(Docker Desktop) with following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'
services: 
   mongodb_container:
        image: mongo:latest
        container_name: mongodb
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=test
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        volumes:
            - mongodb_data_container:/data/db 

volumes:
     mongodb_data_container:
```

When I tried to authenticate database by using `docker-compose up -d --build`, `docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash` and `mongo -u root -p root --authenticationDatabase test`, It produced the following error with the log:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=test&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-04-23T14:22:56.890+0000 E  QUERY    [js] Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-04-23T14:22:56.893+0000 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-04-23T14:22:56.894+0000 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

and when I tried to download a data from local database scheduled with airflow set up by docker-compose, it produced error with following logs:

```
[2020-04-23 14:30:15,763] {taskinstance.py:1128} ERROR - 127.0.0.1:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 966, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/missing_title.py", line 32, in download_db
    df =  pd.DataFrame(list(collection3.find())).drop(['_id'], axis=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1156, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1050, in _refresh
    self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1810, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1763, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1796, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 485, in get_server_session
    None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 209, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 127.0.0.1:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

How can I access the MongoDB database with docker-compose? (When I tried to download a data from the MongoDB database locally with pymongo and Jupiter notebook outside docker, I can)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line:

```
- MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=test
```

from the docker compose file, and set your authentication database to admin (the default)

```
mongo -u root -p root --authenticationDatabase admin
```

That will sort out the first problem.

For the second problem, configure the connection to use the container name, e.g. `mongodb:27017` rather than `127.0.0.1:27017`

Comment: For the second problem, it might be solved (?) because instead the usual log error, it become "command require authentication" error. while for the first problem, I have tried the steps you mentioned and it still produced the same error of requiring authentication

Comment: Sorry I messed up, the authentication database should be admin, I've corrected the answer to `mongo -u root -p root --authenticationDatabase admin`

Answer (score 0):

"Connection refused" means you have a network connectivity error. The client doesn't get to authentication at all. Troubleshoot that first.